# PHP not sending data to database

Tags: php

I am getting this error while trying to make a register form:

> Could not find your email in our database
>
> Cannot send confirmation link to your email address

Why would it not be sending?

**This is the PHP:**

```
<?php

    include('config.php');

    //test to see if username is alphanumeric
    $testname = $_POST['username'];

    if (!eregi('([^A-Za-z0-9])',$testname)){
        //test for duplicate names
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$_POST[username]'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ($num == 0){
            //test for duplicate emails
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$_POST[email]'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            $num2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

                if ($num == 0){
                    //test if emails and passwords match up
                    if(($_POST['pass']==$_POST['pass2'])&&($_POST['email']==$_POST['email2'])){

                        //generate random confirmation code
                        $confirm_code = md5(uniqid(rand()));

                        //get rid of all html from hackers
                        $name=strip_tags($_POST['username']);
                        $email=strip_tags($_POST['email']);
                        $pass=strip_tags($_POST['pass']);

                        //insert data into database
                        $sql="INSERT INTO temp SET code='$confirm_code',username='$name',email='$email',pass='$pass'";
                        $result3 = mysql_query($sql);
                            if ($result3){
                                $message = "Your Confirmation link \r\n";
                                $message .= "Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
                                $message .= "localhost/PHPTUT/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";

                                $sentmail = mail($email,'Registration Confirmation',$message,'From: email@example.com');
                                header("Location:thankyou.html");
                            }else{
                                echo 'Could not find your email in our database';
                            }

                            //if your email successfully sent
                            if($sentmail){ // **LINE 47**-------------------
                                echo 'Your confirmation link has been sent to your email address.';
                            }else{
                                echo 'Cannot send confirmation link to your email address';
                            }
                    }else{
                        header("Location:badmatch.html");
                    }
            }else{
                header("Location:emailinuse.html");
            }
        }else{
            header("Location:nameinuse.html");
        }
    }else{
        header("Location:invalidname.html");
    }

    ?>
```

**This is the Form:**

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="registernext.php">
    <p>Username:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="username" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""></p>
    <p>Password:</p>
    <p><input type="password" name="pass" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""></p>
    <p>Confirm Password:</p>
    <p><input type="password" name="pass2" size="25" maxlength="20" value=""></p>
    <p>Email:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="email" size="25" maxlength="65" value=""></p>
    <p>Confirm Email:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="email2" size="25" maxlength="65" value=""></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: If email is not found - then `$sentmail` is not defined.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this. Use parameterized queries. Update your driver as well, `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `$sentmail` is not set in all if-else branches. When the email is not found in the database, there is nobody who sets it to false and the following line will produce the notice:

```
                        if($sentmail){ // **LINE 47**-------------------
```

To avoid it, set default `false` somethwhere at the beginning:

```
$sentmail = false;
```

Comment: That worked, but now I am still getting "Could not find your email in our database. Cannot send confirmation link to your email address"

Comment: @catsaremlg bcz its execute else part and yur query $result3 = mysql_query($sql); not working